# Swift: Filter the results in a table view so it does not return duplicates from the JSON

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I have a JSON file that I am pulling values from into a table view based on a key. I want my table view to only show a value if it is not already in the table. In other words, I only want values in the table once, even if they are associated with the key multiple times.

In this particular case. Every entry in the JSON file is associated with 1 of 9 media industries. If the media industry has already been printed to the table view, I do not want to see it in the table view a second time.

Here is the code I have. I have not been able to figure out how to prevent duplicates. This shows every value even if it is a repeat.

```
    func parseJSON(){
    do{
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/580d0ccce4b0bcac9f837fbe")!)

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

        for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{

            let mifiIndustry2 = anItem["mediaIndustry"] as! String

            let newIndustry = Industry(industryName: mifiIndustry2)
            industryOfMifi.append(newIndustry)
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IndustryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as? IndustryCell{

        let industry: Industry!
        industry = industryOfMifi[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(industry)
        return cell

    } else{
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a set to check if the value is a duplicate quickly.

Before your for loop, declare a Set:

```
var industrySet = Set<String>()
```

Right after you set the variable for mifiIndustry2, check if the set contains mifiIndustry2:

```
 let mifiIndustry2 = anItem["mediaIndustry"] as! String
 if !(industrySet.contains(mifiIndustry2)) { 

    //if the set doesn't contain the string, add it so that you can check for it again later
    industrySet.insert(mifiIndustry2)

    //since it passed the check and is not a duplicate, initialize it as Industry and add to industry array 
    let newIndustry = Industry(industryName: mifiIndustry2)
    industryOfMifi.append(newIndustry)
}
```